# Postgresql Simple IF ELSE Statement

Tags: postgresql

In MS SQL I can execute a statement like:

```
Declare @foo int = 1, @foo1 int = 42
IF @foo <> 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @foo
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @foo, @foo1
    END
```

Does anyone have any idea how to run this statement on postgresql?

EDIT: MS SQL Example like :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spIFtest 
    @p1 int = 1, 
    @p2 int = 10,
    @isFilter bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
IF @isFilter = 1
    BEGIN
    SELECT idx FROM rw.octest where idx between @p1 and @p2
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT idx FROM rw.octest
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) With caveats:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    foo integer := 1;
    foo1 integer := 42;
BEGIN
    IF foo <> 0 THEN
        PERFORM foo;
    ELSE
        PERFORM foo, foo1;
    END IF;
END;
$$
;
```

`DO` cannot return anything.

You can fake a return:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    foo integer := 0;
    foo1 integer := 42;
BEGIN
    IF foo <> 0 THEN
        SELECT INTO foo 1;
        RAISE NOTICE 'foo is %', foo;
    ELSE
        SELECT INTO foo, foo1 1, 42 ;
        RAISE NOTICE 'foo is %, foo1 is %', foo, foo1;
    END IF;
END;
$$
;

NOTICE:  foo is 1, foo1 is 42
DO
```

Answer (score 0):

**In PostgreSQL `DO` Block can execute the queries but they can not return any value.
So the first part of your question is not possible directly in postgresql.**

For second part of your question: In `PostgreSQL` you can use Function (which is very powerful and effective) like below:

```
create or replace function spiftest()
returns table(idx_ int)
as $$
declare
p1 int := 1;
p2 int := 10;
isfilter boolean := 0;

begin

if isfilter then
return query 
SELECT idx FROM octest where idx between p1 and p2;
else
return query 
SELECT idx FROM octest ;
end if;


end;

$$
language plpgsql
```

calling above function for result:

```
select * from spiftest()
```

You can write it with parameters also like below:

```
create or replace function spiftest(p1 int, p2 int, isfilter boolean)
returns table(idx_ int)
as $$

begin

if isfilter then
return query 
SELECT idx FROM octest where idx between p1 and p2;
else
return query 
SELECT idx FROM octest ;
end if;


end;

$$
language plpgsql
```

to call above function

```
select * from spiftest(1,10,'t')
```